# Pentaho: Binary file (standard input) matches

Tags: linux, pentaho, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

When I'm trying to use MySQL in Table input with an **order by** in the query, I'm getting below error and ETL stops abruptly.

```
Binary file (standard input) matches
```

If I remove **order by** in the query, it works. Is this a bug in Pentaho?
And, it occurs only in Linux Environment

I'm using Pentaho 8.1.0.0 CE
OS: Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS 
MySQL Driver version: mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar

Comment: What is the source table structure and what does the transformation do? Without more detail, we can do little more than guess or Google the error message. Google returns lots of results about Grep. Are you searching through files?

Comment: @Cyrus I'm just doing 
`select * from table_name where start_date > '1970-01-01 00:00:01' order by start_date limit 10000`
also removing limit also causes same issue.

Comment: So there is a row beyond 10k that causes problems. "Order By" brings that row into the first 10k, removing the limit also makes you reach the problem row. Are there BLOB fields or such in the table that might hold a lot of data?

Comment: @Cyrus All are normal datatypes. No BLOB fields. There's no problem if I run it on MacOS

Comment: If you put the Table Input in its own transformation, only connected to a dummy step, does it still happen (on Linux)?

Comment: @Cyrus  yes, still same error

Comment: Searching the web i found some entries about possible compressed files or logrotate, i'm not an Linux user so i have no idea what is happening, but this might be worth a shot .. [Web Link](http://msutic.blogspot.com/2008/07/one-of-most-important-obligations-for.html)

Comment: was your problem solved @HemanthS.Vaddi? I am getting the same error in the table output step.

Comment: @PuneetSidhu, I rewrote the whole thing in a new transformation and it worked normally. Try the below answer also, it might work if there are any such date values in your query output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checks whether the select is returning a zero date 0000-00-00 00:00:00

If so, add the property zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull in the JDBC parameters

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me also in Ubuntu 16.04 and PDI 8.1 (although it worked fine in Windows 10 and PDI 8.1)

In my case happened by a step that had an accent in the name.

Try to keep the names of the steps simple, without accents or any other fancy characters.